# Recursive function to check that user input is numerical

Tags: python

I have made a simple recursive function to check whether user input both numerical and within predefined lower and upper bounds.

If my input is correct the first time then it returns the int version of the user input, but if I enter either a string not convertible to an int or a number outside the valid range (0-10000), the function returns nothing. The exit clause seems to be working fine and dandy.

Why is this happening?

```
def check_is_numeric(user_input, min_val=0, max_val=10000,
                     not_a_number_blurb=" is not a number. Please enter a number between ",
                     not_in_range_blurb="That number is out of range. Please enter a number between "):
    try:
        number = int(user_input)
        if min_val <= number <= max_val:
            return number
        else:
            check_is_numeric(input(f"{not_in_range_blurb}{min_val} and {max_val}: "))
    except:
        if user_input.lower() == 'exit':
            exit()
        else:
            check_is_numeric(input(f"{user_input}{not_a_number_blurb}{min_val} and {max_val}:"))


print(f"The value passed back from check_is_numeric is: {check_is_numeric(input('Enter a number: '))}")
```

Comment: Are you asking for user input on every call on purpose?

Comment: `check_is_numeric(input(...))` → `return check_is_numeric(input(...))`

Comment: I think so. I want the user keep trying until they enter a number between 0 and 10000.

Comment: @aaron: of course. That's the solution! It's achingly obvious now! Thanks a million! If you want to make an answer, I'll acknowledge it as I should!